# PHPstorm FTP can't upload files

Tags: ftp, phpstorm

Im trying to configure my PHPstorm with FTP so after a file is saved, it needs to be uploaded to the host. I can connect (i did the test) but i can't upload a file unless i change the file permission to 777 of my file. Any idea how this is possible? Here is the error:

```
[31/01/16 17:11] Failed to transfer file '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/yventure.nl/app/Http/Controllers/Website/HomeController.php': cant open output connection for file "ftp://mm.server/app/Http/Controllers/Website/HomeController.php". Reason: "550 app/Http/Controllers/Website/HomeController.php: Permission denied".
[31/01/16 17:11] Automatic upload completed in less than a minute: 1 item failed
```

EDIT: i've enabled passive mode already

Answer (score 8):

I had same issue. I solved it

with "Passive Mode" in "Advanced Options" in Deployment >> FTP settings.

Answer (score 3):

you must try and valided :

- the user right
- the group right
- SSH key/pair connexion
- directory right
- **SFTP connection (not FTP)**